# RxJava2: Alternative to rx.Observable method first(predicate)

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex, rx-java2

I wanted to use RxJava but can't come up with alternative for method

```
public final Observable<T> first(Func1<? super T,java.lang.Boolean> predicate)
```

in RxJava2.

What I want to do is following:

```
return io.reactivex.Observable
    .concat(source1, source2, source3, source4)
    .first(obj -> obj != null);
```

Parameters source1 to source4 are `io.reactivex.Observable` instances that I concatenate and I want resulting Observable to emit only the very first item that isn't null but this of course fails because `io.reactivex.Observable` doesn't have method `first(Func1 predicate)` like `rx.Observable`.

What are my options if I have any in RxJava2 or is it better to stick with RxJava1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using `Maybe` instead of `Observable` of nullable type (it won't work with *RxJava2*). Then use `Maybe.concat` to get only emitted items as `Flowable`. And just get the first element with `first` to return `Single` (you have to specify a default item) or `firstElement` to return `Maybe`:

```
Maybe.concat(source1, source2, source3, source4)
    .firstElement()
```

Answer (score 3):

RxJava2 doesn't allow emitting **null** value as suggested by the others.

If, however, the predicate for determining what that first value to be returned is not to checking null, you may then consider using `.filter` before `.first` (need specifying some default value) or `.firstOrError` (emit OnError instead if nothing matched)

```
return io.reactivex.Observable
    .concat(source1, source2, source3, source4)
    .filter(obj -> obj == someAnotherObj)
    .firstOrError();
```

Answer (score 1):

first was renamed to firstElement. Also, Rx 2.0 doesn't support null values on the stream.

[Rx.Java 2.0 Doc - 1.0 x 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#operator-differences)